# Pull date of a file using excel vba

Tags: excel, vba

I have problem with the date in excel. When i try to pull the date of the file inside a folder, it will pull the hour,min and second although the coding didn't ask for it. Finally i found that the abnormal date in  the excel cell show data at alignment right,whereas the correct data show data at alignment left.  This will affect the abnormal sorting problem. Please help and thanks.

```
NextRow = Sheets("Sheet1").Cells(Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row + 0
For Each objFile In objFolder.files
Sheets("Sheet1").Cells(NextRow, 1).Value = Format(objFile.DateLastModified, "dd/mm/yyyy")
NextRow = NextRow + 1
Next objFile
Sheets("Sheet1").Range("C1").Sort Key1:=Range("C2"), Order1:=xlAscending, Header:=xlYes
```

Excel:

[image]

Visual Basic:

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Replace `"dd/mm/yyyy"` with `"mm/dd/yyyy"` - VBA internally is using the US format!

Alternatively, you can simply store the date value without conversion. Internally, Excel will convert your date string back to a date number anyway! :-)

Thus, simply use this line:

```
Sheets("Sheet1").Cells(NextRow, 1) = objFile.DateLastModified
```